# Enjoyhint - How to use getCurrentStep() inside onNext global event?

Tags: javascript, enjoyhint

I am building an user tutorial using **Enjoyhint** library. I am not using the main repository (https://github.com/xbsoftware/enjoyhint) but a fork (https://github.com/zapper59/enjoyhint) because the first one contain a lot of issues and seams to not be maintened anymore.

I want to save in database the **current step** of the user in the tutorial in each step. 
The documentation said to use `getCurrentStep` function.

I want to use it in the global `onNext` function while I create my enjoyhint instance like the following :

```
    let that = this; //this here is pointing in vue.js view instance, you don't need to care about that
    var enjoyhint_instance = new EnjoyHint({
        onNext:function(thut = that){
            console.log(thut);
            console.log(this);
            thut.$store.dispatch('userTuto/SET_CURRENT_STEP', this.getCurrentStep());
            console.log(this.getCurrentStep());
        }
    });
```

`This` inside the `onNext` function is like that :

```
{container: "body", onStart: ƒ, onEnd: ƒ, onSkip: ƒ, onNext: ƒ, …}
animation_time: 800
container: "body"
onEnd: ƒ (thut = that)
onNext: ƒ (thut = that)
onSkip: ƒ (thut = that)
onStart: ƒ ()
__proto__: Object
```

**My problem :**

I can't use `getCurrentStep()`, it's undefined, it has to be `enjoyhint_instance.getCurrentStep()` but I can't use it because I haven't contruct it yet. 
Does anyone now How I can retrieve the currentStep inside the Enjoyhint constructor to use it inside global `onNext` function ?

Answer (score 1):

Declare you instance globally then create a separate function to call the getCurrentStep function.

```
var enjoyhintInstance;

    var showUserGuide = function() {
    enjoyhintInstance = new EnjoyHint({
        onNext : function () {
            console.log(getHintCurrentStep());
        }
    });
}

var getHintCurrentStep = function() {
    return enjoyhintInstance.getCurrentStep();
}
```